# problem with module Magento_Customer after upgrade magento to 2.2.2

Tags: magento-2.1

I have updated magento from 2.1.1 to 2.2.2.

The update was successful, but now when I enter the site I see the error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Customer db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.9

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please update your modules: Run "composer install" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Customer db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.9
#0 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#2 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#8 /home/brandswearxv/ftp/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#9 {main}
```

Anyone know how to solve it ?

EDIT:
error after run command: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

[image]

In log exception is code:

```
[2018-02-01 10:25:43] main.CRITICAL: Asymmetric transaction rollback. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Asymmetric transaction rollback. at /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:316)"} []
[2018-02-01 10:44:36] main.CRITICAL: Asymmetric transaction rollback. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Asymmetric transaction rollback. at /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:316)"} []
```

Comment: Sounds like your upgrade was not entirely successful. Was there any error output when you ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ?

Comment: @sduif I update my subject after run command setup:upgrade, please check. Thanks.

Comment: The error comes from the `Magento_Integration` module (Model\AuthorizationService.php). Sounds like it's having trouble with some of your data in authorization_role or authorization_rule. But I'm unfamiliar with any error of this kind unfortunately, sorry. Maybe you can try posting your issue over at the Magento Github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: in that case, it will reinstall magento. Thank you for your try help!